# expression web: Import website but save remote pictures saved locally on hard disk?

Tags: expression-web

I have imported a website using Import of expression web 4. Works great but the pictures are remote URL (http) links. Is there anyway to force them to be downloaded and the url of the img pointed to the local saved image?

Or is there a feature where i can right click on an img and force it to be downloaded locally in expresion web 4?

I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought Expression Web does this automatically upon saving the HTML file?

Otherwise, try downloading the website completely offline (e.g. with [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)) and work with this version from within Expression Web.

Comment: Thanks Uwe, no it doesn't save it automatically but i am giveing httrack a try. thanks